# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds-Pairs of array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java.I want to understand how ArrayIndexOutOfBounds can be solved.In C language we do not get this exception.Why does this happen in java.

I have come across certain solutions like try catch block.However,I am not satisfied.I am using netbeans IDE.

```
public class Logpairs 
{
    static int arr1[]={1,2,3,4,5};

     static void pairs(int arr[])
     {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i)
        {
          for(int j=0;j<arr.length;++i)
            {
               System.out.println("{"+arr[i]+","+arr[j]+"}");
            }
        }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       pairs(arr1);
    }
}
```

The actual output should be all pairs of array.Example:{1,1} {1,2} {1,3} {1,4} {1,5} {2,1}.....{5,5}
However, my output is only {1,1} {2,1} {3,1} {4,1}{5,1}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Comment: Because you're doing ++i twice

Comment: Debugging is your friend. As Zachary mentioned, this line is wrong: "for(int j=0;j<arr.length;++i)". You're incrementing the "i" instead of "j"

Answer (score 2):

Try this, increment j instead of i twice.

```
public class Logpairs 
{
    static int arr1[]={1,2,3,4,5};

     static void pairs(int arr[])
     {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i)
        {
          for(int j=0;j<arr.length;++j)
            {
               System.out.println("{"+arr[i]+","+arr[j]+"}");
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: This was helpful.Thank you.If possible can you also let me know why does this exception arise in Java but not in C programming language?

Comment: @Preena Darshini C does not define what error occurs when you access an array index out of bounds, it can create a segmentation fault for example.  You still aren't _allowed_ to access an out of bounds element though, you will get unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a clear idea on this.